# Why is adding objects to my model so slow?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, optimization, linq-to-entities

I have a SimID query that joins a given list of cell phone numbers with their respective IDs in my DB, if the number doesn't exist in the DB it returns 0 as an ID. If I watch my query while debugging, it executes perfectly and very quickly. However when I loop through the results of the query and create a new object and add it to my model it takes 3 minutes to create 458 new objects.

I am new to EF and Linq what am I doing wrong? How can I optimize this code to execute faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Query to create virtual table of SimID and MSISDN joined on Cache.MSISDN
var SimID = (from ca_msisdn in Cache.MSISDN
             join db_simobj in ctx.Sims on ca_msisdn equals db_simobj.Msisdn into Holder
             from msisdnresult in Holder.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { MSISDN = ca_msisdn, ID = (msisdnresult == null || msisdnresult.SimId == 0 ? 0 : msisdnresult.SimId) });

//Loop through virtual tables and add new data to model
foreach (var ToUpdate in SimID)
{
    if (ToUpdate.ID == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We have found a new MSISDN: " + ToUpdate.MSISDN + " adding it to the model.");
        ctx.Sims.Add(new Sim { Msisdn = ToUpdate.MSISDN });
    }
}

//My Sim object
public partial class Sim
{
    public Sim()
    {
        this.CDR_Event = new HashSet<CDR_Event>();
    }

    public long SimId { get; set; }
    public long SimStatusId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> FitmentCentreId { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Msisdn { get; set; }
    public string Puk { get; set; }
    public string Network { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SimStatusDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActivationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> APNSimStatusId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> APNActivated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> APNConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string Svr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CDR_Event> CDR_Event { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question as IronMan84 alluded to; as documented [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs) is to use .AddRange() and add everything all at once as a list outside the foreach instead of one by one inside the loop.

```
List<Sim> _SIMS = new List<Sim>();
foreach (var ToUpdate in SimID)
{
    if (ToUpdate.ID == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We have found a new MSISDN: " + ToUpdate.MSISDN + " adding it to the model.");
        _SIMS.Add(new Sim { Msisdn = ToUpdate.MSISDN} );
    }
}
ctx.Sims.AddRange(_SIMS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that every time that you add to the `Sims` collection on your context you are adding to what the context's change tracker needs to keep track of, which can become a very expensive proposition memory-wise when you start having larger amounts of entities.

You can solve this in one of two ways:

1) Save the data in batches. That way the change tracker never has to keep track of a large amount of added entities.

2) If you don't want to save it right away, keep it as an in-memory list first, and then do #1 when you do go to save those records.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply :). Do you think doing a raw SQL insert would help? It's Ugly but if there are any other solutions I would love to learn about them.